# A way to find all sub-objects of another object, which contains lists, at runtime

Tags: java, xml, list, generics, jaxb

I have a project, which is based off of an XML schema which is subject to change. The schema is converted to Java using JAXB. Several parts of the schema are guaranteed to remain constant; in particular, a base element for a form that users have to fill out.

I am to generate a form based upon this (subject-to-change) JAXB-generated code. The issue is that because my code is constant, but the schema could be changed at any time, I cannot hard code in any of the JAXB code, excepting the base element.

Therefore, I must recursively find all of the elements below the base object. This isn't too much trouble at all, with a little reflection magic (Find the return type of all of the object's 'getter' methods, repeat). The real issue is when I encounter a list. Because lists lose their type at runtime, I am unable to determine what the list contains, and cannot recurse any further.

Does anyone have a brilliant solution for getting around this? I've looked into most every other way to preserve a lists type at runtime, but none have worked. I'm well aware that this is probably impossible, but I want to explore all of my options before I give up. If there is any other way to do this, I'm willing to try it.

My current code:

```
public static void getObjectDescendants(Object obj, int indent) throws Exception {
    // Handle list of objects.
    if (obj instanceof List) {
        for(int i=0;i<indent;++i){System.out.print("  ");}
        System.out.println("List");
        Class<?> clazz = getListType((List<?>) obj); // Get type of object within list

        // Create new object of that type from constructor. (temp solution)
        Object object = clazz.getConstructor().newInstance();

        getObjectDescendants(object, indent+1);
        return;
    }

    // Handle regular object.
    for (MethodDescriptor pd : Introspector.getBeanInfo(obj.getClass()).getMethodDescriptors()) {
        // For each method this object has...
        Method method = pd.getMethod();

        // If it does not return a complex object, or a list, we don't care about it.
        if (!method.getReturnType().toString().contains("JAXB.generated.object")
                && !method.getReturnType().toString().contains("java.util.List")) {
            continue;
        }

        // Print out indent, and name of method.
        for(int i=0;i<indent;++i){System.out.print("  ");}
        System.out.println(method.getDeclaringClass().getSimpleName() + "." + method.getName() + "()");

        Object object;
        try {
            if (method.getReturnType().equals(List.class)) {
                object = method.invoke(obj);
            } else {
                Constructor<?> constructor = method.getReturnType().getConstructor(String.class);
                object = constructor.newInstance();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            continue; // Couldn't seem to handle this one.
        }

        getObjectDescendants(object, indent+1);
    }
}

private static Class<?> getListType(final List<?> list) {
    // Find out what object type is in the list, and return it.
    Class<?> clazz = list.get(0).getClass(); // Doesn't work, since list is always empty.
    return clazz;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of going with reflection into JAXB Classes, you could use JAXB models. When you create JAXB context from classes or packages, it creates an underlying model of those classes and their properties. In the runtime - based on annotations. During the compile time (XJC) - based on the XML schema.

This is implementation-specific, so I'll take JAXB RI as I know it better than MOXy.

- When you create `JAXBContext` with JAXB RI, you'll get an instance of `JAXBContextImpl` at the end.
- This has a method `getTypeInfoSet()` returning an instance of `RuntimeTypeInfoSet`.
- This `RuntimeTypeInfoSet` is the whole and complete model of JAXB classes, properties - everyting you need for marshalling and unmarshalling.
- For complex types you'll have `RuntimeClassInfo` instances which have properties (`RuntimePropertyInfo`)

You can analyze these structures an build your UI in runtime. It is much easier than digging reflection. Basically this `Runtime...` stuff does all the necessary reflection beneath so you don't have to do this.

By the way, I'd personally not reinvent the wheel here and go with one of existing model-driven UI generation approaches, for instance [Metawidget](http://metawidget.org/). You'll have to connect the framework to the JAXB model, but it seems to be easier than doing the whole thing from scratch.

Around 7-8 years ago I've implemented XML Schema-driven UI generation for based on JAXB, was quite an adventure. There are quite a few caveats.